# (I assume trivial) floor function problem.

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

**Question.** What is the floor of $$x=\frac{5(\sqrt{13}+2)}{9}.$$

---

**My attempt.** For brevity; I will denote $f(x)$ as the floor of $x$. Now, observe $3<\sqrt{13}<4$. Then, my naive approach has $$f\Big(\frac{5(\sqrt{13}+2)}{9}\Big)=f\Big(\frac{5\cdot 3+10}{9}\Big)=f\Big(\frac{25}{9}\Big)=2.$$ But having looked this value up in a calculator, it is rougly $3.1141...$ which gives the floor of $3$ of course.

---

So where have I gone wrong?

---

**Reflection.** Thank you to *all* that have helped me with this. I will be wary on improving my bound next time.

Comment: Hint: what is the floor of $2\cdot (2/3)$?  Can you take the floor of $2/3$ first?

Comment: $\sqrt {13}\approx 3.6$.  Just knowing $\sqrt {13}>3$ isn't that helpful...we also have $\sqrt {13}>0$...would you just plug $0$ in?

Comment: @Lulu is right. Basically you just need to improve your bound.

Comment: You have to give a better approximation for the square root. You gave a lower bound, I am guessing that the upper bound (i.e. replacing by 4 instead of 3) gives you that the floor you're looking is less or equal than 4.

Comment: Note that $5\sqrt{13}=\sqrt{325} > \sqrt{324}=18$

Comment: Use $\left\lfloor\mbox{}\right\rfloor$ for the $\texttt{Floor Function}$. For instance, $\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor\ \LaTeX\!-\!\texttt{MathJax}$ code is
 $\texttt{\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ 325 > 289  $$
$$  \sqrt{325} > \sqrt{289}  $$
$$  \sqrt{5^2 \cdot 13} > \sqrt{17^2}  $$
$$ 5 \sqrt {13} > 17  $$
$$ 5 \sqrt {13} + 10 > 27  $$
$$ 5 ( \sqrt {13} + 2) > 27  $$
$$ \frac{ 5 ( \sqrt {13} + 2)}{9} > 3  $$

Answer (score 1):

You've gone wrong in assuming that you could just substitute the $3=\lfloor\sqrt{13}\rfloor$ when caluculating the floor of an expression containing $\sqrt{13}$. Just to show you how wrong that is $\lfloor 5\sqrt{13}\rfloor=\lfloor\sqrt{325}\rfloor\approx\lfloor 18.027756\rfloor=18$ while $5*\lfloor\sqrt{13}\rfloor=15$.